# Не работает скролл в фрагментах

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview, coordinator-layout

Есть список из `cardview`, который создается при помощи адаптера и выводится с помощью фрагмента.

`layout` куда выводится список выглядит следующим образом:

```
list_page_fragment.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
   >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_list_refresh"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_refresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`FloatingActionButton` служит для обновления данных.

Подумалось... возможно ли появление этой ошибки из-за того, что вывод с помощью фрагмента обусловлен наличием табов со свайпом и программа читает только свайпы влево-вправо?
Выглядит все это так, а сам скролл `cardview` не работает :(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Cама инициализация `адаптера` обыкновенная:

```
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
        adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), names);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Думаю ошибка все равно останется, если использовать ListView вместо CardView.

## update

**разметка activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/view">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:title="@string/app_name"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:background="@color/primary_light"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/background"
            android:id="@+id/viewpager">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

также листинг **ListFragment.java**. В нем получение информации из БД, занесение ее в ArrayList и передача данных в адаптер.

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {
private final String TAG = "WHALETAG";
private FloatingActionButton fabRefresh;

private DBhelper dbHelper;

public static RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

public ListFragment() {}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    fabRefresh = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab_list_refresh);

    fabRefresh.setOnClickListener(clickRefresh);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}

View.OnClickListener clickRefresh = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        dbHelper = new DBhelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); // подключаемся к бд

        Log.d(TAG, "Обновление данных");
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) // ставим позицию курсора на 1 строку выборки. Если строк нет = false
        {
            // определеяем  номера столбцов по имени
            int idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("id");
            int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");

            do { // получаем значения по номерам столбцов
                Log.d(TAG, "ID = " + cursor.getInt(idColumnIndex) + "; " +
                        "Key = " + cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex));
                names.add(cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex)); // добавили строку в список
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "0 столбцов таблицы");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Таблица пуста", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
        adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), names, recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        cursor.close();
    }
};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_page_fragment, container, false);
}
```

}

На английском stackoverflow парень пишет, что ошибка возможна из-за того, что включать `recyclerView` нужно в `onCreateView` но приложение крашится, когда я пытаюсь это сделать.

Comment: Ошибка неизвестно где. Создайте пустое приложение, добавьте туда ваш фрагмент и должно заработать. Единственное - "гравити" списку - зачем? Приведите ещё разметку активити. Может у вас ещё слушатель скрола какой где стоит.

Comment: Действительно, гравити списку совершенно незачем)
Слушателей скролла нет нигде. Разметка main_activity.xml? Не понимаю зачем, но добавил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего ваша проблема в том, что вы `ViewPager` поместили в `AppBarLayout`.

Переместите его в `CoordinatorLayout` и должно заработать.

Также у вас, почему-то, `scrollingViewBehaviour` нигде не указан...